# Scraping list in R

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, rvest

I want to scrape a list of elements (name player, cost, buyer, seller, day) from a local HTML file, but I have a problem with the **2** and **3** when i try to scrape buyer and seller (in this case for the 1st transfer 'Computer' and 'Peter') and for the 2nd transfer 'Computer' and 'james')

```
document.querySelector("#pressReleases > ul > li:nth-child(**2**) > ul > li.text > div > strong:nth-child(2)")

document.querySelector("#pressReleases > ul > li:nth-child(**3**) > ul > li.text > div > strong:nth-child(2)")
```

How can **scrape** the `li` elements making this 2 variable?

I've tried this in R:

```
dades<- mylocalfile

player<-dades %>% html_nodes("ul.player li.text strong") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
cost<-dades %>% html_nodes("ul.player li.text span") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
buyer<-dades %>% html_nodes("#pressReleases > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.text > div > strong:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
seller<-dades %>% html_nodes("#pressReleases > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li.text > div > strong:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
day<-dades %>% html_nodes("ul.player li.text time") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
```

I detected that this 2  `#pressReleases > ul > li:nth-child(2)`  is variable for each `li class="post pressRelease"`

The html code:

```
<div class="newsList" id="pressReleases">
<ul>
 <li class="date" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);">
   <strong>Fitxatges del dia</strong>
    09/08/2019
  </li>
  <li class="post pressRelease">
    <ul class="player">
      <li class="photo">
        <img src="./futmondo - Fútbol fantasy manager - futmondo_files/espanyol.png" onerror="Futmondo.Helpers.Resources.onErrorPlayerPhoto(this, &quot;L&quot;, &quot;espanyol.png&quot;)">
        <img src="./futmondo - Fútbol fantasy manager - futmondo_files/espanyol(1).png" alt="Espanyol" class="crest">
      </li>
      <li class="text">
         <strong>Player1</strong>
         <time>09/08/2019 - 05:30</time>
         <span>16.245.485 €</span>
         <div class="from">
           D'
         <strong>computer</strong>
           a 
         <strong>peter</strong>
        </div>
       </li>
      <a class="icon-revert">
      </a>
     </ul>
     <div class="bid second">
        <span class="triangle"></span>
        <strong class="second">2º puja</strong>
        <strong>matheu:</strong>
        <span class="price">15.925.828 €</span>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post pressRelease">
    <ul class="player">
      <li class="photo">
        <img src="./futmondo - Fútbol fantasy manager - futmondo_files/real-sociedad.png" onerror="Futmondo.Helpers.Resources.onErrorPlayerPhoto(this, &quot;L&quot;, &quot;real-sociedad.png&quot;)">
        <img src="./futmondo - Fútbol fantasy manager - futmondo_files/real-sociedad(1).png" alt="Real Sociedad" class="crest">
      </li>
      <li class="text">
       <strong>Player2</strong>
       <time>09/08/2019 - 05:30</time>
       <span>1.111.711 €</span>
       <div class="from">
          D'
         <strong>computer</strong>
          a 
         <strong>james</strong>
       </div>
      </li>
      <a class="icon-revert">
      </a>
    </ul>
   </li>
```

Comment: can u add real link on web-page?

Comment: is like a fantasy manager. is this http://www.futmondo.com but you have to login to acces to your league and then acces to market where you can view the code therefore i paste the code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to get the `buyer/seller`:

```
# Read the local file
URL <- 'D:/Test/Test.html'
wp <- xml2::read_html(URL, encoding = 'utf-8')
# Extract the relevant nodes
node <- rvest::html_nodes(wp, '.from')
# Extract the names
seller <- gsub('.*D\'\r\n\\s+(.*?)\r\n\\s+a\\s?\r\n\\s+(.*?)\r\n.*', '\\1', rvest::html_text(node))
# [1] "computer" "computer"
buyer <- gsub('.*D\'\r\n\\s+(.*?)\r\n\\s+a\\s?\r\n\\s+(.*?)\r\n.*', '\\2', rvest::html_text(node))
# [1] "peter" "james"
```

Comment: hi niko, thanks for your answer but the result is "computer peter" "computer james" in the same cell when I export the results in excel, and i want computer in one column and peter in other column.

Comment: @xuriguer The `node` object contains the buyer/seller in the same _cell_ (in one character object). However, with `gsub` we extracted the buyer/seller: the two vectors `buyer;seller` contain the buyer/seller of each transaction (see `data.frame(buyer, seller)` - an _Excel-like_ structure with the data in separate cells). So I'm affraid if you are still facing an issue, it lies with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried for buyers

```
#pressReleases .from strong:nth-child(1)
```

and for sellers

```
#pressReleases .from strong:nth-child(2)
```

Assuming you have read html into variable `page` then (extend to include your other vars)

```
buyers <- page %>% html_nodes("#pressReleases .from strong:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text
sellers <- page %>% html_nodes("#pressReleases .from strong:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(buyers,sellers))
```

The dataframe then should be easy to export.